# There was an error in compiling the proxy code

Tags: wcf

I have created a very simple wcf serivce and I am trying to use it in Agilepoint nx, but it is giving me this error:

```
Exception: AgilePoint.Workflow.DataSources.DynamicProxyException: There was an error in compiling the proxy code.
   at AgilePoint.Workflow.DataSources.DataSourceDescriptorWCF.OpenWsdl(String urlStr, String domainName, String userName, String userPassword, Boolean isGenerateMessageContract, DynamicProxyFactory& _factory)
   at AgilePoint.Workflow.DataSources.DataSourceDescriptorWCF.GetWCFBindingsAndEndpoints(String URL, Boolean generateMessageContract, String CustomDomainName, String CustomUserName, String CustomUserPassword)
   at r.GetWCFBindingsAndEndpoints(String wcfServiceUrl, Boolean generateMsgContract, String credentials)
Compilation Errors:
error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll' could not be opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '
```

Anyone any idea what could be causing this error?

I have changed the identity in app pool to: Localsystem, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Test your web service with wcftestclient or SoapUI.
Looks like you should enable 32bit apps in app-pool settings (if you are hosting service in IIS).

Comment: I have tested the service in wcftestclient and created a console application and it is running fine. I have also enabled 32bit app in application pool, but the problem was that the pool was stopping all the time and the service was unavailable.

Comment: If it is stopping - then you getting another error (not mentioned above)?